# How to wait for blueprint service being bind

Tags: java, osgi, blueprint

I'm new to the Blueprint service and I looked for any sample to satisfy the requirement of waiting the service being up in a reference-listener context.

I have a core bundle which provide some kernel services (db, network etc.), and I wrap it with  the interface like the following (blueprint.xml):

```
<bean id="ServiceImplBean" class="com.mysite.service.impl.ServiceImpl" factory-Method="getInstance"/>
<service id="MyServiceInterface" ref="ServiceImplBean" interface="com.mysite.service.IService"></service>
```

In another bundle I'm using the reference listener to listen for the service being up and running, blueprint like following:

```
<bean id="ServiceHolderBean" class="com.mysite.consumer.ServiceHolder" factory-method="getInstance" />
<reference id="ServiceHolderBeanReference" interface="com.mysite.service.IService">
    <reference-listener ref="ServiceHolderBean" bind-method="bind" unbind-method="unbind" />
</reference>
```

And here's the class of ServiceHolder piece which take the IService into its field and hold for further usage:

```
public class ServiceHolder {
    private static ServiceHolder instance = new ServiceHolder();
    private IService service;

    private ServiceHolder() {
    }

    public static ServiceHolder getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void bind(IService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void unbind(IService service) {
        this.service = null;
    }

    public IService getService() {
        return this.service;
    }
}
```

The intention is that in the consumer bundle I can easily use the `ServiceHolder.getInstance().getService()` to utilize that service.

The problem is sometimes the service is required at initial phase of the bundle start or just before the service is registered. Obviously I'll get a null when call the getService().

What would be the best practice to use blueprint to fulfill the service need when bundle start? I think I can use something like `while (service == null) { Thread.sleep(5000)'};` but it looks pretty bad. Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say you do not need this `ServiceHolder`. The OSGi service registry is the master "service holder" for your container. Once you have the `<reference id=...>` you can inject that ref into any consumer where you are trying to use the `ServiceHolder`. The container will take of the ordering for you.

Comment: Thanks, I figure out that I should inject my service into the actual biz logic and it will wait until the service being up and running and continue execute. Thanks much.